# munin using apache virtual host

Tags: apache, munin

I have been playing with Munin lately (v2.0.25) and would like to use it with a virtual host in apache.

I have read the docs that go through using apache as a reverse proxy, but I figure, since the munin graphs are built into a folder in the web root, i can make a virtual host that uses that as the doc root, and treat is as a subdomain.

This works as expected, no problems. However I noticed that the munin apache.conf file seems to be symlinked to the apache available-conf dir at install time, and so this is still active, meaning there are two URLs which will point to the same content. My solution to this was simple and brutal - delete the symlinks, and again, it works. But there has to be a cleaner way, right?! A config setting i've missed?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found an 'official' way to achieve this, so I think your approach is totally valid.

Personally I chose to disable the munin apache conf with: `sudo a2disconf munin`, which has the same effect. That way there's no need to delete the symlink.

Comment: cheers! my biggest concern on this matter, of course, is what happens when Munin updates? The config will probably come back, and, unless I catch it, I have a config that is unexpected